# How can I render text on specific days in Fullcalendar v4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm new in using Fullcalendar io. For example, I want to render the "Hello World" on January 1, 15, and 30 2020. How do I do that in Fullcalendar v4?

```
dayRender: function(dayRenderInfo) { dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = "<p>Hello World</p>"; }
```

Want to achieve something like this. Just a plain text:

[image]

Comment: As `event` ? or what?

Comment: @Pedram Hmm not as an event, but just a plain text

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with `dayRender` function.

```
$('#my_calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'month',
  events: [{
    title: 'some-event',
    start: '2020-01-01 10:00',
    end: '2020-01-01 19:00',
  }],
  dayRender: function(date, cell) {
    cell.append('<div class="custom-class">Hello World</div>');
  },
 });
```

**EDIT:**
On version 4 it changed to an object (from their [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3)):

So you should compare the column date to you dates, for example:

```
dayRender: function(info) {
  let colDate = new Date(info.date);
  let myDates = [
    new Date('2020-01-01'),
    new Date('2020-01-15'),
    new Date('2020-01-30'),
  ];

myDates.forEach((date) => {

  if (colDate.getYear() === date.getYear() &&
      colDate.getMonth() === date.getMonth() &&
      colDate.getDate() === date.getDate())  {
    info.el.innerText = 'hello'
  }
  });
}
```